# IntelliJ doesn't see modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm just starting with Java development. I installed JDK and IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13. Then I want to create new project. But when I select it, there are no options other than some kind of "Groovy". I don't see "Console project" or anything else, just groovy. I think something went wrong with my IDE, please help me. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `Next` and you will see this:

[image]

Check `Create project from template` > `Command line App`

You don't need to choose `Groovy` if you don't need it.